# Send a pdf file inside the email's body

Tags: c#, email, back

I need to incorporate a pdf file inside a string that will be the body of my email, because the structure of my email does not contain attachments. 
Can anyone give me any ideas?

Comment: Meaby this will help You [link](https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=8#c-send-email-with-embedded-images-example)